# How to handle parameters on C# server side sent from jQuery POST?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to send the following data from jQuery on the server side like so:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('name', 'tyler');
fd.append('hello', 'world');
$.post('/NMISProduct/Index', { submitData: fd}, function(returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData);
}, 'json');
```

How do I handle this on the server side?  Here is what I have, which I'm sure is very wrong:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(string submitData)
{
    return submitData;
}
```

I just want to return what I send to C# back to jQuery so I know it got there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `myData`? what is the error if it does not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach ties you to `FormData()` and it doesn't take advantage of JSON.Net which is happy and eager to deserialize your object so that you can consume it.

If you truly want to test "full-loop", deserialize to a strongly typed object and return it back to the client as serialized json, building out the matching object on the client instead of using `FormData()`.

```
$.post('/NMISProduct/Index', { name: 'tyler',hello: 'world' }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormData submitData)
{
    return Json(submitData);
}

public class FormData 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _"What you have technically works"_. No it doesn't (it will throw an _Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation_ error) because posting `FormData` requires explicitly setting the `processData: false,` and `contentType: false,` ajax options. Based on the code you have shown (which is the correct approach), the script needs to be `$.post('/NMISProduct/Index', { name: 'tyler',hello: 'world' }, function() {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It didn't even occur to me that it was THE FormData object.  Thank you for pointing it out.  I've updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys - unfortunately, I am tied to using the official JS `FormData` object as that is the only way you can upload files via AJAX (which is what I need to do), unless that isn't actually the case.  I'm basing this knowledge from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Then you need to use `$.ajax()` (not `$.post()`) so that you can set the correct options. Suggest you also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)